# OS X Yosemite suspends inactive windows

Tags: safari, macos, javascript

I have some user script that runs every about 10 minutes on specific page at opened tab in Safari 8.

The surprise is that safari somehow suspend javascript execution when tab is not active by user for a while.

The question is how to force javascript execution and prevent this behavior?

**UPD:** actually the same behavior is detected in Opera. I think the problem is  related to `Yosemite` release?

Comment: Use another browser? JavaScript execution works fine in background tabs when I use Chrome.

Comment: Actually even in the Chrome with `prevent app nap` checked option, when the tab is not active it not executes javascript properly...

Answer (score 1):

It might be going into "App Nap"

To disable this for Safari go to Finder, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and check "Prevent App Nap": 
[image]

You can check to see if it worked by going opening up Activity Monitor, clicking the Energy tab and seeing if Safari is in sleep mode.

Comment: Actually I didn't have this option in Yosemite for Safari and iPhoto. It has only `Locked` checkbox. But this option exists for Chrome which is worked perfect without any changes :-/

Comment: No, I missed something. Even with checked option in Chrome, if the tab is not active - it doesn't work.